# Client denied by server configuration while trying to use git-http-backend.exe

Tags: windows, git, apache

I use apache 2.4

```
Sat Oct 06 15:25:47.948789 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 7580:tid 1232] [client 192.168.100.252:10153] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe
```

Here is my configuration

```
<Directory "C:\git-server">
Options +ExecCGI
Allow from all
</Directory>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot  "C:/git-server"
   ServerName ****
  DirectoryIndex index.php

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT c:/git-server
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"


<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/git-server/config/users"
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
Options +ExecCGI
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile "C:/git-server/config/users"
Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>


</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying 2 days to setup git. i didnt expect that it was that difficult.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should change your configuration to match the needs of Apache 2.4:

```
<Directory "C:\git-server">
Options +ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access

Comment: weird though. the document (link) states that there is a compatible module access_compat.load but even with this enabled you still need to modify the directory statement. (at least in my case.) else it wont work!

Comment: I followed [this tutorial](http://www.diggin-data.de/website/post/37-Installing+Git+http-backend+on+Windows+with+XAMPP) that noted the pre-2.4 way; your answer, as well as the remark about copying *libiconv-2.dll* to *git-core* from [that tutorial](http://www.oudmaijer.com/2011/07/19/git-server-on-windows/) got my setup ready to use.

Comment: That didn't help in my case (Also I'm under Linux). Instead I had to use the `<Files>` and the path to the executable, not the path to the HTTP (GIT) data.