# Client denied by server configuration for Git and Apache

Tags: git, apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure a Git server on windows server 2008 R2 with a Apache 2.4 server.

I added this to the httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "C:/serveur_web">
Options +ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/serveur_web
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

I created a repository in `C:/serveur_web` I typed this command to clone it with my remote machine:

```
git clone http://dladev1/parc_auto
```

I received this error:

```
C:\Users\assontia>git clone http://localhost/parc_auto
Cloning into 'parc_auto'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://localhost/parc_auto/': The requested URL returne
d error: 403
```

In my apache error.log I can see this :

```
[Thu Jun 26 02:44:50.404296 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 2852:tid 816] [client 10.52.66.78:60785] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe
```

I am wondering if this is because I do not have rights to access the git server anonymously?

Do I need to automatically create users to use the git server?

This question does not help me to resolve my issue : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759854/client-denied-by-server-configuration-while-trying-to-use-git-http-backend-exe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client denied by server configuration while trying to use git-http-backend.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759854/client-denied-by-server-configuration-while-trying-to-use-git-http-backend-exe)

Comment: @cweiske, probably not a duplicate since he has the `Options +ExecCGI` which was the solution for the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent two hours to find out that the directory where you need to authorize the execution of CGI *scripts* needs to be the directory where the CGI is and not the directory where you have the GIT data.

So this is wrong since that directory is where you placed your GIT data:

```
<Directory "C:/serveur_web">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

We can see in your setup that the server is here:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
```

Which means the directory that needs CGI authorization is something like this:

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core*">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You need to authorize all the executable because it uses several. I suppose that you could determine what those are and only allow exactly what's required. But when I tried to include the exact name of the executable it was still giving me a 403.